# Asp.Net Website extension for visual studio 2012 express for windows desktop

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Currently,I have Visual studio 2012 express for windows.I want to build asp.net website on it but it currently does not have any provision for it.What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install either:

- [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30669)
- [Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44912)

Or, and this depends on your situation

- [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517284)

Which is actually a free version of Visual Studio Professional which can be used based on your financial or organisational situation. It's free for open source, academic and "small businesses":

> ### Q: Who can use Visual Studio Community?
>
> A: Here’s how individual developers can use Visual Studio Community:
>   Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.
>
> Here’s how Visual Studio Community can be used in organizations:
>
> - An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.
> - For all other usage scenarios: In non-enterprise organizations, up to 5 users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or > $1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.
>
> For more information, please refer to the [Visual Studio Community 2013 License Terms](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550) and the [Visual Studio Licensing Whitepaper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)</sup>

All of these versions can be installed side-by-side. Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition will actually provide one integrated environment where you can build both web and desktop applications in the same solution.

Comment: Thanks.But is there a way in which i can download some extensions for visual studio for windows desktop so that my requirement is met?

Comment: No. Express for **Desktop** is for writing **Desktop** applications. And Visual Studio Express does not support extensions. What's keeping you from using Express for Web or the Community Edition, which *is* made for creating web applications?