# Starting With Web Development Using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I badly need some help. I have installed a Visual Studio 2012 Express here, I've been using this IDE for a quite some time now, for my WPF/WinForm VB.NET/C# projects. Now, I'm planning to study developing ASP.NET Web Applications. But when I create a new project, I can't seem to find an ASP.NET Template or a blank Web Application project.

[image]

Questions:

1. How to install ASP.NET or whatever I need to install for Web Development in Visual Studio 2012 Express?
2. Do I need to download Visual Studio Express 2013 FOR WEB ? (http://www.asp.net/vwd) Can't I just do my number 1 question?
3. Where can I find a step by step tutorial for setting up all IDEs, etc... that I need to install (like MS SQL or MySQL if possible) and connect it to Visual Studio for ASP.NET development?

Please bear with me as this will be my 2nd time to be in Web development using ASP.NET.

I have experience in connecting mySQL database to my projects in C#/VB.NET WPF/Winform applications.

Thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind that SO doesn't like tutorial requests

Comment: Considered downloading the full, free *visual studio 2013 community edition*? which has full support for everything.

Comment: ok thanks guys, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924138/asp-net-website-extension-for-visual-studio-2012-express-for-windows-desktop -- this thread tells me that my current IDE isn't for web development. I'll try to download 2013 for web. Thanks again.